# Issue with Update and Create in Ruby on Rails and JS web app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble with saving a new sneaker that's created and updated. The below is what I have in my sneakers_controller.rb:

```
class Api::V1::SneakersController < ApplicationController

    def index
      sneakers = Sneaker.all
        
      render json: SneakerSerializer.new(sneakers)
    end
    
    def create
      sneaker = Sneaker.new(sneaker_params)

      if sneaker.save
        render json: SneakerSerializer.new(sneaker), status: :accepted
      else
        render json: {errors: sneaker.errors.full_messages}
      end
    end

    def show
      sneaker = Sneaker.new(sneaker_params)

      if sneaker
        render json: SneakerSerializer.new(sneaker)
      else
        render json: {errors: sneaker.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessible_entity
      end
    end

    def update
      sneaker = Sneaker.find(params[:id])
      if sneaker.update(sneaker_params)
        render json: SneakerSerializer.new(sneaker), status: accepted
      else
        render json: {errors: sneaker.errors.full_messages}
      end
    end

    def destroy
      sneaker = Sneaker.find(params[:id])
      sneaker.delete
      render json: SneakerSerializer.new(sneaker)
    end
    
    private
    
    def sneaker_params
      params.require(:sneaker).permit(:name, :description, :image_url, :quantity, :shoe_size, :category_id)
    end

end
```

The following is what I currently have in my index.js file:

```
const endPoint = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sneakers"

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // fetch and load sneakers
  console.log("DOM is Loaded");
  getSneakers()

  const createSneakerForm = document.querySelector("#create-sneaker-form")

  createSneakerForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => createFormHandler(e))

  const sneakerContainer = document.querySelector('#sneaker-container')
  // render edit form once its clicked
  sneakerContainer.addEventListener("click", e => {
    
    const id = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id);
    const sneaker = Sneaker.findById(id);

   if (e.target.dataset.action === 'edit') {
     console.log('you pressed edit')
     const editSneaker = document.querySelector('#sneaker-container')
     editSneaker.innerHTML = sneaker.renderUpdateForm();
      
   } else if (e.target.dataset.action === 'delete') {
     console.log('you pressed delete')

     deleteSneaker(sneaker)

   }

  });

   
  document.querySelector('#sneaker-container').addEventListener("submit", (e) => updateFormHandler(e))
  const sneakerEl = document.getElementById('create-button')

  const sneakerDiv = document.getElementById('create-message')

  const onSneakerClick = function() {
    sneakerDiv.textContent = "You've Created a New Sneaker, Please look at the newly added Sneaker on your list below!"
  }

  sneakerEl.addEventListener("click", onSneakerClick)
});


function updateFormHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const id = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id)
  const sneaker = Sneaker.findById(id)
  const name = e.target.querySelector('#input-name').value
  const description = e.target.querySelector('#input-description').value
  const imageUrl = e.target.querySelector('#input-url').value
   
  const quantity = e.target.querySelector('#input-quantity').value
  const shoeSize = e.target.querySelector('#input-shoeSize').value
  const categoryId = parseInt(e.target.querySelector('#input-categories').value)

  patchSneaker(sneaker, name, description, imageUrl, quantity, shoeSize, categoryId)
}

function patchSneaker(sneaker, name, description, imageUrl, quantity, shoeSize, categoryId) {
  const bodyJSON = { name, description, imageUrl, quantity, shoeSize, categoryId }
  fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sneakers/${sneaker.id}`, {
  
    method: "PATCH",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(bodyJSON),
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    
    .then(sneaker => {
      console.log(sneaker)
      debugger
      let updatedSneaker = new Sneaker(sneaker.data, sneaker.data.attributes)

      let sneakerContainer = document.querySelector('#sneaker-container') 

     sneakerContainer.innerHTML += updatedSneaker.renderSneakerCard();
      location.reload(endPoint)
    })
    // location.reload(endPoint)
}

function getSneakers() {
  fetch(endPoint)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(sneakers => {

    const mappedSneakers = sneakers.data.map( e => e)
    mappedSneakers.sort( (a, b) => {
      
      if ( a.attributes.name < b.attributes.name ){
        return -1;
      }
      if ( a.attributes.name > b.attributes.name ){
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    })

    // debugger

    console.log(`sneakers.data are equal? ${sneakers.data == mappedSneakers}`)
  
    mappedSneakers.forEach(sneaker => {

        let newSneaker = new Sneaker(sneaker, sneaker.attributes)

        let sneakerContainer = document.querySelector('#sneaker-container')

        sneakerContainer.innerHTML += newSneaker.renderSneakerCard();

    })
  })
}


function deleteSneaker(sneaker) {

  fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sneakers/${sneaker.id}`, {

    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json",
    },
    
  })
  .then(response => response.json());

location.reload(endPoint) 
}


function createFormHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const nameInput = document.querySelector('#input-name').value
  const descriptionInput = document.querySelector('#input-description').value
  const imageInput = document.querySelector('#input-url').value
  const quantityInput = document.querySelector('#input-quantity').value
  const shoeSizeInput = document.querySelector('#input-shoeSize').value
  const categoryId = parseInt(document.querySelector('#categories').value)

  postSneaker(nameInput, descriptionInput, imageInput, quantityInput, shoeSizeInput, categoryId)
}

function postSneaker(name, description, imageUrl, quantity, shoeSize, categoryId) {
  // confirm these values are coming through properly
  // build body object

  const bodyData = {name, description, imageUrl, quantity, shoeSize, categoryId}

  fetch(endPoint, {
    // POST request
    method: "POST",
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    body: JSON.stringify(bodyData)
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(sneaker => {
     

    let newSneaker = new Sneaker(sneaker.data, sneaker.data.attributes)

    let sneakerContainer = document.querySelector('#sneaker-container')
       
    sneakerContainer.innerHTML += newSneaker.renderSneakerCard();  
  })
}
```

The following is what is console logged from the debugger that was placed in my patch request and when I console log sneaker I get the following error:

```
errors: Array(1)
0: "Category must exist"
length: 1

index.js:78 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined
    at index.js:78
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

P.S I have added my schema file below:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_06_15_203829) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "sneakers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "description"
    t.string "image_url"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.integer "shoe_size"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "category_id", null: false
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_sneakers_on_category_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "sneakers", "categories"
end
```

Comment: There are a few unrelated bugs/idiosyncrasys in your controller. Since the controller is actually saving the record and its syncronous you can return `201 - Created` instead of `202 - Accepted`. You're also missing a `:` at `status: accepted` which will give a NoMethodError. When it comes to a delete request you might want to just respond with `200 - OK` and no body.

Comment: @max 204 is a good status code for a destroy action imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Category must exists, sounds like a validation error from your Sneaker(?) Model;

If you are using `belongs_to :category` rails adds a presence validation for that, too. Try changing it to: `belongs_to :category, optional: true` or also transmit a valid category_id, which seems to be missing.

Try also check your logs, or Browser Dev Tools (network tab) and inspect the Request Body of the api call.

Comment: I get the following message now: ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  
insert or update on table "sneakers" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_9ae2c9b08c"
DETAIL:  Key (category_id)=(4) is not present in table "categories".
):

app/controllers/api/v1/sneakers_controller.rb:13:in `create'

Comment: This is the request payload: {name: "Air Jordan 1 Retro High OG 'Pine Green 2.0'", description: "",…}
categoryId: 4
description: ""
imageUrl: "https://image.goat.com/crop/500/attachments/product_template_additional_pictures/images/032/436/952/original/496584_08.jpg.jpeg?1581012121"
name: "Air Jordan 1 Retro High OG 'Pine Green 2.0'"
quantity: "8"
shoeSize: "4.5"

Comment: Your first comment says it: you are transmitting a category_id = 4, but there is not Category with id=4 in the categories table, ergo the insert failes on the Foreign Key Constraint that you've set by using t.belongs_to in the migration.
Try submitting a valid category_id from a category that exists in your Database.